# C# database error, Changing items in listbox from another listbox

Tags: c#, database, winforms, listbox

I have searched for an answer to my problem, but I could not find a solution specifically for my problem, so I have to make another post.

I want to change the items in the player listbox when I select another item in the teams listbox.

For example if I select team1 in teams listbox, I should get the players of team 1 in player listbox.

My program fails at the adapter.fill(playertable) part and I get error:

> System.ArgumentException : No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type.

I have created 3 sql tables which are player, team and team_player , which works as assosiative table between player and teams.

Also if I try to get the value of selected item in the teams listbox by `Messagebox.Show(listboxpteams.SelectedValue.ToString())` I dont get the value but I get System.Data.DataRowView.

here is my code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    string connectionString;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Peehootee.Properties.Settings.playersConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void Form2_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fillteams();

    }

    private void fillteams()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name  FROM team", connection))
        {
            DataTable teamtable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(teamtable);

            listboxteams.DisplayMember = "name";
            listboxteams.ValueMember = "Idteam";
            listboxteams.DataSource = teamtable;
        }
    }
    private void populateplayers()
    {
        String query = "Select a.firstname+ ' ' + a.surname AS Name, From player a inner JOIN team_player b on a.Idplayer = b.playerid where b.teamid = @Idteam";
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idteam",listboxteams.selectedvalue);

            DataTable playertable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(playertable);
            listboxplayers.Displaymember = "Name";
            listboxplayers.ValueMember = "Idplayer";
            listboxplayers.DataSource = playertable;

        }
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void listboxteams_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       populateplayers();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The query that fills the listbox with teams has no field named _idteam_ Typo or a critical error?

Comment: The query that populate players is incorrect (comma after the last field) This seems a typo otherwise you should get a syntax error exception at the first use of the query (and again _idplayer_ is missing in the query text)

Comment: The query works, I tested it. I guess I have a typo on this post since Im not getting syntax error. My player tables primary key is Idplayer, team tables primary key is Idteam and assosiative tables foreign keys are playerid and teamid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is caused by the missing field *idplayer* in the query text you use to fill the listbox. Without this field it makes no sense setting the ValueMember property to a field that you haven't retrieved from the database.  When you try to read the SelectedValue the binding engine doesn't know what to return to your code, so it returns the name of the class used to bind the DataTable to the ListBox (A DataRowView)

By the way, if you exchange the order of the properties settings you will get an ArgumentException stating exactly what is the problem

Try this....

```
listboxplayers.DataSource = playertable;
listboxplayers.Displaymember = "Name";
listboxplayers.ValueMember = "Idplayer";
```

An ArgumentException occurs when you set the ValueMember property.

Fix your queries both in the player and team query to include *idplayer* and *idteam*

first here...

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT idteam, name FROM team", connection))
```

and also ....

```
String query = @"Select a.idplayer, 
                        a.firstname+ ' ' + a.surname AS Name 
                 From player a inner JOIN team_player b 
                          on a.Idplayer = b.playerid 
                 where b.teamid = @Idteam";
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, Now it works perfectly! I thought that the problem cant be in my query, but seems that the main problem was just that :D Well best mistakes are those that you learn from!